# session values are disappearing

Tags: php, session, redirect

I have a form which posts some data to a script which processes these data. After the processing the user is redirected to his main page. On this main page I call a function which clear some session values for me:

```
function clearSessionValues(){
        file_put_contents('evil.txt', chr(10) . date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time()), FILE_APPEND);
        $sessionValues = $_SESSION;
        foreach($sessionValues as $key=>$value){
            if($key != 'angemeldet' && $key != 'username' && $key != 'usergroup'){
                unset($_SESSION[$key]);
            }
        }

    }
```

The funny thing is that my script which processes the form is missing some values from the `$_SESSION` array. If I comment out the function call on the main page or the commands in this function, everything is working fine. What's the reason for this?

I tried to rename the function. I also tried to log the function call and the function is called. It seems the processing has not finished, but the redirect takes place. So fast that the values are cleared before they can get accessed. I store the needed value at the beginning of the script ...

What can I do against this?

Comment: Have you tried using `sleep()` at the start of the function?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija: Yeah I tried it (with a too high value) and now I'm waiting and waiting ... (despite I canceled the request). I couldn't test it now. But let the user wait is not the best option.

Comment: Putting the script to sleep for about 2 seconds should solve your issue. I would not recommend putting it to sleep for more than that.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija: Can you explain why this happens? Is it because of multiple threads or something like that? Now I tried it with `sleep(2);` without success. I'm stilling getting the error that the value in the seession couldn't be found.

Comment: From what I understand from your query, the problem seems to be a race condition. While PHP is setting the `$_SESSION` data, you start clearing it through your main page.